# Qt 6.2.4 for QNX710 on Ubuntu 20.04 - Qt version is not properly installed

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator, qnx

I tried to build Qt 6.2.4, installed via qt-unified-linux-x64-4.3.0-1-online.run on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in a Virtual Box.
[image]

I installed Qt 6.2.4 in ~/Qt6 for Desktop gcc 64-bit and in source code.

QNX 7.1 is installed in ~/qnx710.

I sourced qnxsdp-env.sh:

```
$ . ~/qnx710/qnxsdp-env.sh
```

I added Qt6.2.4, Ninja and CMake to PATH:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:~/Qt6/6.2.4/gcc_64/bin
$ export PATH=$PATH:~/Qt6/Tools/Ninja
$ export PATH=$PATH:~/Qt6/Tools/CMake/bin
```

Copied the qnx.cmake example from https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/building-qt-for-qnx.html#creating-a-toolchain-file-for-qnx

```
$ cat ~/cmake_support/toolchains/qnx.aarch64le.cmake 
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME QNX)

set(arch gcc_ntoaarch64le)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER qcc)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET ${arch})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER q++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET ${arch})

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT $ENV{QNX_TARGET})
```

Created a build directory and configured qt:

```
$ mkdir ~/Qt6/6.2.4/qnx_build
$ cd ~/Qt6/6.2.4/qnx_build
$ cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/cmake_support/toolchains/qnx.aarch64le.cmake -DQT_HOST_PATH=~/Qt6/6.2.4/gcc_64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/Qt6/6.2.4/qnx ../Src
```

Compile and install

```
$ cmake --build . --parallel && cmake --install .
```

This all went fine.

Then I tried to add the new Qt Version to Qt Creator, but this fails with Qt version is not properly installed, please run make install.
Details: Invalid Qt version.

[image: 1f784bbb-84f7-4bad-9485-418f8c0441b7-image.png]

And of course, once creating a kit, it fails and can't be used.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Qt version was indeed not properly installed.

qmake expects a specific directory for target libraries

```
$ ~/Qt6/6.2.4/qnx/bin/qmake -v
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 6.2.4 in /home/werner/qnx710/target/qnx7/home/werner/Qt6/6.2.4/qnx/lib
```

So to fix QT Creator, I simply had to create a symbolic link:

```
$ cd ~/qnx710/target/qnx7
$ mkdir -p home/werner
$ ln -s ~/Qt6 .
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful -- thank you. Just to clarify a bit for others who find themselves in a similar scenario, running the newly built `qmake -v` will tell you where qmake is expecting to find the Qt libs. For some reason `cmake install` didn't actually install the libs to the expected location, so if qmake can't find them there, creating a symlink as this answer suggests is a viable workaround.